# How to have different intervals between x axis labels

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

Hi I want to have a graph that looks like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lEKL.png)

Where as you can see the x axis is not linear it jumps from 20 to 60

Right now when I try to plot this I get this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9RYE.png)

There is an equal spacing between all xticks.

What I am currently doing is to convert the numbers to strings but I want to know is if there is another way of doing this keeping the numbers as numbers